# Как передать класс объекта в качестве параметра?

Tags: java, android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.btnGallery:
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClassName1.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           break;
       case R.id.btnNew:
           intent = new Intent(this, ClassName2.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           break;
       case R.id.btnPrice:
           intent = new Intent(this, ClassName3.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           break;
       case R.id.btnCallBack:
           intent = new Intent(this, ClassName4.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           break;
       ...
   }
}
```

Так как здесь много однообразной работы (вызов activity), то хотелось бы оптимизировать.

Что-то вроде этого:

```
public void classUsing (String s) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, s.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.btnGallery:
           classUsing(ClassName1);
           break;
       case R.id.btnNew:
           classUsing(ClassName2);
           break;
       case R.id.btnPrice:
           classUsing(ClassName3);
           break;
       ...
    }
 }
```

Как передать название класса в виде аргумента в другой метод и там его использовать?

Comment: Можно было просто `startActivity(intent)` вынести за кейсы и все. Будет намного лаконичней, чем писать отдельный метод.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<ИмяКласса>.class` имеет тип `Class`. Вы можете передать в метод класс как параметр таким образом:

```
public void doSomething(Class clazz) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, clazz);
}
```

Использование метода:

```
doSomething(Class1.class);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как собственно передать название класса?

т.к

 case R.id.btnGallery:
               classUsing(ClassName);
               break; 

вызывает ошибку

Comment: @user208111 `classUsing(ClassName.class); `

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!!! =)